# como quitar controller/Action de la url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hola a todos en el proyecto .net mvc cuando ejecuto la url sale

```
http://miweb.dominio.com/home/index
http://miweb.dominio.com/home/about
http://miweb.dominio.com/Products/index
```

quisiera que solo me mostrara http://miweb.dominio.com para todos los controller y las acciones

he intentado con esto:

```
[Route("")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Y sin un ruteo (los valores después del dominio) cómo es que el servicio sabrá que controlador/método cargar? o tal vez no estoy entendiendo bien la pregunta.

Comment: hola KodiakMx  no tengo mucha experiencia en esto, pero he visto web que no muestra nada despues del dominio hechas en .net mvc y pense que habia alguna variante, por eso preguntaba

Comment: Muy probablemente esas paginas están desarrolladas en angular o react, y solo el back end es lo que está construido en mvc.

Answer (score 1):

estuve buscando lo mismo, quizás mucho tiempo después, pero encontré una solucion y es que si tu controlador y accion son las principales, puedes rutearla de la siguiente forma en el RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute("", "{action}/{id}", new {controller = "MyController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});

// default route
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} );
```

Saludos.